# Error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I looked over on stackoverflow but I still can't figure what's wrong with the code.
PS: I am a beginner 
/****************************************************************/

```
class Main 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    int SIZE = 10;
    int[] sortedArray = new int[SIZE];
    int[] intArray = new int[]{ 5,2,10,4,1,6,99,8,9,1 };
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    // Random big nunbver to ensure no number in array is bigger
    int biggestNumberFound = 10000000;
    int maxValue=0;
    for ( x = 0; x <= SIZE; x++) 
      for ( y = 0; y <= SIZE; y++)
        maxValue = 0;
        if (intArray[y] > maxValue && intArray[y] < biggestNumberFound)
          maxValue = intArray[y];
      sortedArray[x] = maxValue;
      biggestNumberFound = maxValue;
    System.out.println(sortedArray);
  }

}
```

/***********************************************/

The error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
exit status 1

Comment: It should be `< SIZE`

Comment: This means that in line 17 of Main.java you access an array element with index 11 that does not exist.

Comment: change x <= SIZE to x < SIZE

Comment: arrays are zero based, therefore the valid range in this case is 0 to 9. The for loop iterates from 0 to 10, hence the error

Comment: Also, you have problems with scopes, add curly brackets after each for loop and specify area which this loop should affect

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( x = 0; x <= SIZE; x++)
```

x should less than SIZE instead of `<=` since array begin with index 0 and end with (size-1)

Comment: I've tried with x<SIZE and I still get the same error

Comment: @CatalinPadurean there is exactly the same problem with `y` as well.

Comment: Done for y as well, forgot to mention

Comment: @Catalin Padurean and please add some `{` before and `}` after for block

Comment: `for (x = 0; x <SIZE; x++) {
   for (y = 0; y < SIZE; y++) {
    maxValue = 0;
    if (intArray[y] > maxValue && intArray[y] < biggestNumberFound)
     maxValue = intArray[y];
    sortedArray[x] = maxValue;
    biggestNumberFound = maxValue;
   }
    
  }`

Comment: Thank you so much guys.

Comment: @CatalinPadurean - just for clarification, when you didn't add brackets, your for loop used to execute before the executing the condition, **if (intArray[y] > maxValue && intArray[y] < biggestNumberFound)** and the value of y being 10, you were getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. I got that after I put the brackets. Thanks for the explanation :)